# How can print correctly with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello I am trying to print a  and I am using bootstrap to add some of style to the info inside the , the problem is that when I try to print the page bootstrap adds extra space, and I cannot remove or expand the , how can do it? Thanks.

The doted lines are the corners of the page.

Stiles:

```
@media print {

    .page {
        width: 100%; 
        float: none;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }


    body {
        line-height: 1.3;
        color: #000;
        width: 100%; 
    }

}


body {
    background: rgb(255,255,255); 
    color: var(--darkgray) !important;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }

page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm; 
    float: none;
    page-break-after: always;
    border: dotted 2px;
}
```

Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">     </head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/25f01b61a0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        </head>

        <body>
        <page>

        </page>
        <page>

        </page>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I use bootstrap:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I get this:

[image]

But when I remove that line I get this:

[image]

And I want to print the  enterly.

How can solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `<page>` a valid html tag? And you're also loading tailwind. Not sure if its good idea to use two frameworks at the same time.

Comment: No i define page in the css

Comment: If I remove tailwind, the page is wrong when try to print anyway.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a A4 document in a html web page that prints as it looks?

Comment: correct, I am triying to do a template to documents in html.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very tricky scenario. My answer is not a solution.

In relation to my code below, the problem is with scaling. If my `.page` div was imported into an `<iframe>` and then scaled using css `transform`, that would give the appearance of a A4 single page document (like a PDF). So as you scale down to mobile, `.page` would shrink down like an A4 previewed document.

But then you got other things to consider, multiple page overflow, print margins, web responsiveness... it's technical.

The safest bet it just use bootstraps standard `.container` class on a div and build your page content inside it. This way you can overflow onto two pages. Simply use bootstraps basic css classes for text, tables etc and you should be golden.

Bootstrap on its own handles this nicely. You can add an extra `@media print` style to remove the padding on `.container`. so your content fills the page.

Heres my experimental code below but this is not a good solution, it depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Practicality is where I would steer towards.

```css
BODY {
  background: darkgray;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.page {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(100% / 8.27 * 11.65);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

.page-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% / 11.65);
  right: calc(100% / 8.27);
  bottom: calc(100% / 11.65);
  left: calc(100% / 8.27);
}

@media print {
  BODY {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .page {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .page-inner {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="page-inner">

      <h1 class="display-4">Display test title for print</h1>

      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec faucibus aliquet turpis, vel luctus sapien ullamcorper sed. Donec sit amet arcu ut urna tempus consectetur cursus porttitor justo. Vivamus vitae mollis nunc. Donec blandit euismod tristique.
        Nam at sem non urna vehicula hendrerit non ac dui. Sed imperdiet lorem at nisi lacinia, in vehicula eros feugiat. Nulla vitae vulputate mauris, malesuada vulputate erat. Donec eleifend augue eros, at scelerisque ex suscipit in.</p>

      <p>Donec bibendum purus nec fringilla hendrerit. Etiam commodo viverra lorem a hendrerit. Etiam venenatis ultrices ante venenatis facilisis. Nunc purus massa, tincidunt a sollicitudin quis, euismod nec ligula. Donec feugiat enim ac sapien sodales,
        id vehicula diam pharetra. Fusce auctor quis risus pellentesque sagittis. Sed fermentum orci odio, et consectetur velit maximus at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus congue
        ac erat eu vestibulum.</p>

      <hr/>

      <h2>Sub test title for print</h2>

      <p>Mauris id turpis a nisi tempus ullamcorper. Mauris id pharetra ante, id consectetur erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas diam leo, facilisis tempus mauris nec, porttitor ultrices leo. Vestibulum vehicula ullamcorper
        consequat. Maecenas viverra sollicitudin libero, ut faucibus metus tristique sed. Etiam purus magna, luctus non iaculis luctus, molestie nec justo. In molestie, lectus eget feugiat vehicula, nisi libero pulvinar justo, vitae hendrerit mi odio
        a erat. In malesuada eros eu libero varius, sed convallis turpis rutrum. In eu tortor sed elit bibendum volutpat blandit eget ipsum. In varius ex fermentum nisi mattis, id vehicula purus efficitur.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```